# Arduino create an array of structures in a struct

Tags: arrays, struct, arduino

I have the following structs in my Code:

```
struct digitalDataStruct {
    unsigned long timestamp;
    int digitalData;
};

struct analogDataStruct {
    unsigned long timestamp;
    int analogData[16];
};

struct structWithPositionAndCo {
    const int sizeOfDigital = 1000;
    const int sizeOfAnalog = 10;
    digitalDataStruct sensorValuesDigital[];
    analogDataStruct sensorValuesAnalog[];
    int digitalPosition = 0;
    int analogPosition = 0;
    int lastDigitalWriteToPC = 0;
    int lastAnalogWriteToPC = 0;
};
```

And now I wanna to create the Array of the digitalDataStruct and the analogDataStruct.

```
structPackage.sensorValuesAnalog = new analogDataStruct[structPackage.sizeOfAnalog]; // array to store the value coming from the sensor
structPackage.sensorValuesDigital = new digitalDataStruct[structPackage.sizeOfDigital]; // array to store the value coming from the sensor
```

But I still getting this Error:

```
incompatible types in assignment of 'analogDataStruct*' to 'analogDataStruct [0]'
```

any clue?

Comment: What is `structPackage`?

Comment: structPackage is an Object of structWithPositionAndCo

Answer (score 1):

You could make the digitalDataStruct and analogDataStruct members pointers to those respective types instead of arrays.  You will also need a member variable for each to keep track of how many item are in each if it is not a known value that you can hard code.

```
struct structWithPositionAndCo {
const int sizeOfDigital = 1000;
const int sizeOfAnalog = 10;
digitalDataStruct* sensorValuesDigital;
analogDataStruct* sensorValuesAnalog;
int digitalPosition = 0;
int analogPosition = 0;
int lastDigitalWriteToPC = 0;
int lastAnalogWriteToPC = 0;
```

};

Comment: what you exactly mean with "member variable of each..." isn't that sizeOfDigital and sizeOfAnalog?

Comment: Yes it is.  But I don't know if that number changes from one instance of the struct to another because you didn't post any of that code.  If it is a known value then you don't need a member to hold it.  If it isn't the same for all instances then each instance needs to know how many it has.

Comment: Yeah, the value will not change, i put it in the struct, to make it clearly arranged. I also have only one instance of this struct
Now with the Pointers it work, but my compiler don't say anymore how many space of SRAM is used...

Comment: That number that the Arduino spits out for the SRAM used is just what it knows about at compile time like global and static locals.  You're using the new operator, so your arrays aren't created until runtime.  You'll have to calculate that memory by hand.  I see 12 bytes plus 6 per digital and 36 per analog.

Comment: yeah with 1000 elements in the digital array and 10 elements in the analog array I got something about 6360 Byts used

Comment: Plus the twelve in the struct itself, so 6372.  Hope you're not on an UNO.

Comment: No, it is an Mega :)
However, have you a clue why at the beginint the array is filled with random numbers, while I putt in zeros?
` for (int i = 0; i < structPackage.sizeOfAnalog; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
   structPackage.sensorValuesAnalog[i].analogData[j] = 0;
  }
 }`

Comment: I can't imagine how I could possibly figure that out as I can't see your code.

Comment: The Mega only has 8KB of RAM.  I don't know what else you are doing with this Mega but you've already taken up a huge chunk of it.  If your program does much more you may have a memory issue.

Comment: `
 structPackage.sensorValuesAnalog =
   new analogDataStruct[structPackage.sizeOfAnalog];
 structPackage.sensorValuesDigital =
   new digitalDataStruct[structPackage.sizeOfDigital];

 for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  pinMode(digitalPin[i], INPUT);

 for (int i = 0; i < structPackage.sizeOfAnalog; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
   structPackage.sensorValuesAnalog[i].analogData[j] = 0;
  }
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < structPackage.sizeOfDigital; i++) {
  structPackage.sensorValuesDigital[i].digitalData = 0;
 }
`